# JOptionPane output text copy

Tags: java, swing, text, output, joptionpane

I have no experience with `JOptionpane` but I need a simple program to simplify my life.
The code I need help with is below:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String input = "";

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter code");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, toStringU(toArray(input)), "RESULT",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}
```

`toStringU` method gives me a long long text

I want to run it without any compiler (a standalone application, double click, put info and take results).

And I cant copy the result from output panel, which I need to copy. So either I need to copy it and/or I want to write it to a txt file (second one would be great).

Comment: Do you care when this occurs (ie write/copy)?

Comment: yeah i need to copy the output text
and i need it to work without a compiler

Comment: But when?  I can do it before or after the `JOptionPane` is displayed...do you care?

Comment: i dont get it completely i think but the order should be like that

Pane -> input
output -> pane

Comment: Your question doesn't entirely make sense. You have some input (from the user), which produces some output.  You are showing this on the screen.  You know want to either "copy" (presumably to the clipboard) and/or write it to file.  Do you care when these last two operations occur?  I would imagine that copy/write before display would be preferable...

Comment: yeah that would be great. or the output line can be able to copied.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`JOptionPane` allows you to specify an `Object` as the message parameter, if this value is a `Component` of some kind, it will be added to the `JOptionPane` (`String`s are rendered using `JLabel` automatically)

By setting up something like a `JTextArea` that is not editable, you can take advantage of its copying capabilities, with out much more work on your part...

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestOptionPane11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestOptionPane11();
    }

    public TestOptionPane11() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 10);
                ta.setText("This is some really long text that is likely to run over "
                        + "the viewable area and require some additional space to render "
                        + "properly, but you should be able to select and copy parts or "
                        + "whole sections of the text as you, but it should remain "
                        + "no editable...");
                ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                ta.setLineWrap(true);
                ta.setCaretPosition(0);
                ta.setEditable(false);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(ta), "RESULT", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Additional side effects

Another side effect is the fact that the `JTextArea` can actually write it's contents to a `Writer` for you...

```
FileWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new FileWriter("SomeoutputFile.txt", false);
    ta.write(writer);
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Which allows you to write a file as well...

Comment: You're welcome.  Lots of people seem to overlook this little feature of `JOptionPane` ;)

Comment: Too bad they does not appear to be an easy way of doing this.

Comment: @jamie Doing what?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, this, macking the text in JOptionPane copyable. I mean this is not hard, I just wish this functionality was built in.

Comment: @jamie Can't cover every use case/possibility ;)