# Java swing JoptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

i want to create a little game with java swing and i'm trying find how to create something like a joptionpane (to put it inside action listener) but a bit more complex. So till now when the user presses a choise from the menu a joptionpane will pop where he will choose the number of players(2-4).
 After that i want these users to give a name and also choose among the 4 available colors(green blue red yellow, if someone picked blue then the next ones won't be able to choose blue). 
So it has to include a place where the user will write his name and 4 choises.
For example if there are 2 players it should got text and choises for only 2 people. Any hint will be really helpfull. Thank you for your time.
This is my actionListener class code(EDITED):
(EDIT:The only thing i can't figure at the moment is how when a user chooses red for example, blue green and yellow will become setEnabled(false))

```
package testing5;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StartListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public MainFrame theFrame;

        public StartListener(MainFrame frame)
        {
            theFrame = frame;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String[] options = new String[] {"2", "3", "4"};
            int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How many players will take part?", "Number of players",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);
            if(response == 0)
            {
                //theFrame.red.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 15));
                secondWindow(response);
            }
            else if(response == 1)
            {
                //theFrame.blue.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 15));
                secondWindow(response);
            }
            else if(response == 2)
            {
                //theFrame.green.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 15));
                secondWindow(response);
            }
        }


void secondWindow(int response1)
        {
            JRadioButton radioG = new JRadioButton("Green");
            JRadioButton radioR = new JRadioButton("Red");
            JRadioButton radioB = new JRadioButton("Blue");
            JRadioButton radioY = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
            JRadioButton radioG2 = new JRadioButton("Green");
            JRadioButton radioR2 = new JRadioButton("Red");
            JRadioButton radioB2 = new JRadioButton("Blue");
            JRadioButton radioY2 = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
            JRadioButton radioG3 = new JRadioButton("Green");
            JRadioButton radioR3 = new JRadioButton("Red");
            JRadioButton radioB3 = new JRadioButton("Blue");
            JRadioButton radioY3 = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
            JRadioButton radioG4 = new JRadioButton("Green");
            JRadioButton radioR4 = new JRadioButton("Red");
            JRadioButton radioB4 = new JRadioButton("Blue");
            JRadioButton radioY4 = new JRadioButton("Yellow");

            ButtonGroup buttonGroupGreen = new ButtonGroup();
            ButtonGroup buttonGroupRed = new ButtonGroup();
            ButtonGroup buttonGroupBlue = new ButtonGroup();
            ButtonGroup buttonGroupYellow = new ButtonGroup();

            JPanel pan = new JPanel();
            pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
            //1
            JPanel pan1_1 = new JPanel();
            pan1_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            JPanel pan1_2 = new JPanel();
            pan1_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            JTextField tf = new JTextField(15);
            pan1_1.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
            pan1_1.add(tf);   
            pan1_2.add(radioG);
            pan1_2.add(radioR);
            pan1_2.add(radioB);
            pan1_2.add(radioY);
            pan.add(pan1_1);
            pan.add(pan1_2);
            //2
            JPanel pan2_1 = new JPanel();
            pan2_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            JPanel pan2_2 = new JPanel();
            pan2_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));  
            JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(15);
            pan2_1.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
            pan2_1.add(tf2);   
            pan2_2.add(radioG2);
            pan2_2.add(radioR2);
            pan2_2.add(radioB2);
            pan2_2.add(radioY2);            
            pan.add(pan2_1);
            pan.add(pan2_2);

            //buttonGroups
             buttonGroupRed.add(radioR);
             buttonGroupRed.add(radioR2);
             buttonGroupGreen.add(radioG);
             buttonGroupGreen.add(radioG2);
             buttonGroupYellow.add(radioY);
             buttonGroupYellow.add(radioY2);
             buttonGroupBlue.add(radioB);
             buttonGroupBlue.add(radioB2);
            //JDialog
            JDialog jd=new JDialog();
            jd.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            jd.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            jd.setResizable(false);
            jd.add(pan);
            if(response1 == 0) //2 players
            {
                jd.setVisible(true);
            }
            else if(response1 == 1) // 3 players
            {
                JPanel pan3_1 = new JPanel();
                pan3_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                JPanel pan3_2 = new JPanel();
                pan3_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));  
                JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(15);
                pan3_1.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
                pan3_1.add(tf3);   
                pan3_2.add(radioG3);
                pan3_2.add(radioR3);
                pan3_2.add(radioB3);
                pan3_2.add(radioY3);            
                pan.add(pan3_1);
                pan.add(pan3_2);
                buttonGroupRed.add(radioR3);
                buttonGroupGreen.add(radioG3);
                buttonGroupYellow.add(radioY3);
                buttonGroupBlue.add(radioB3);
                jd.setVisible(true);
            }
            else //4 players
            {
                JPanel pan3_1 = new JPanel();
                pan3_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                JPanel pan3_2 = new JPanel();
                pan3_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));  
                JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(15);
                pan3_1.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
                pan3_1.add(tf3);   
                pan3_2.add(radioG3);
                pan3_2.add(radioR3);
                pan3_2.add(radioB3);
                pan3_2.add(radioY3);            
                pan.add(pan3_1);
                pan.add(pan3_2);
                buttonGroupRed.add(radioR3);
                buttonGroupGreen.add(radioG3);
                buttonGroupYellow.add(radioY3);
                buttonGroupBlue.add(radioB3);

                JPanel pan4_1 = new JPanel();
                pan4_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                JPanel pan4_2 = new JPanel();
                pan4_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));  
                JTextField tf4 = new JTextField(15);
                pan4_1.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
                pan4_1.add(tf4);   
                pan4_2.add(radioG4);
                pan4_2.add(radioR4);
                pan4_2.add(radioB4);
                pan4_2.add(radioY4);            
                pan.add(pan4_1);
                pan.add(pan4_2);
                buttonGroupRed.add(radioR4);
                buttonGroupGreen.add(radioG4);
                buttonGroupYellow.add(radioY4);
                buttonGroupBlue.add(radioB4);
                jd.setVisible(true);
            }       
        }
```

Comment: You still have a recent open question that you've not replied to or voted on, and yet you're asking a new one.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Hello again. Actually i've been working on theis all day long my head is going numb ^^. I found that there was no reason to use multiple windows. I completelly forgot about the other question :/

Comment: Yes ryan but it seems a bit complicated to me the way it explains it and my english are not that good. I was hoping for a more easy explanation to understand.

Comment: You should gear your GUI code towards creating JPanels. Then you could create a JPanel that gets all this information, and put in into a JDialog (just like you'd put a JPanel into a JFrame -- nothing complicated about it), and display it. Done.

Comment: Thnx again hovercraft. Gonna take a small break and try this out. Seems not that hard the way you say it.

Comment: Note that my recommendation that you gear your GUI creation to creating JPanels is not just for this situation, but most all situations. If you do this, you can put your JPanels anywhere needed, be that in a JFrame, a JDialog, a JOptionPane, another JPanel, a JTabbedPane, as a "card" in a CardLayout using container...

Comment: He's giving you the building blocks to basically build your own UI for capturing user input in such a way that you can re-use it in any number of circumstances, which is what I would have suggested based on your specific problem.

Comment: `JOptionPane` allows to specify a `Component` as the message, which makes the API very powerful.  This means you could design your basic UI on something like a `JPanel` and simply supply it as the message parameter to the `JOptionPane`, as an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409387/joptionpane-output-text-copy/16409519#16409519)

Comment: First of all i got to say thank you all for your help. I wrote some code and now it does shows the windows with the choises i want. It also doesn't let 2 players pick the same color but i can't figure a way to make the other choises(in the same line) setEnabled(false) when he chooses one of them.