# Adding all lines of output to one JOptionPane window after while loop

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

I am trying to add all of the output records from a regex parsed txt file to one JOptionPane window.  I have created a string to capture, but mine continues to print individual windows.  Any ideas?  Thanks

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (Pattern.matches(titlePattern, line)) {
            String name = "", price="";
            String patternName = "title=\".*?(\")";
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(patternName);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
            if (m.find( )) {
                name = m.group(0);
                //System.out.println("Title: " + name.substring(7, name.length()-1));
            }

            String patternPrice = "Suggested Retail Price:.*?\"";
            String strOutput;

            r = Pattern.compile(patternPrice);
            m = r.matcher(line);
            if (m.find( )) {
                price = m.group(0);
                //System.out.println("Title: " + name.substring(7, name.length()-1) + ", " + price.substring(0, price.length()-1));
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Title: " + name.substring(7, name.length()-1) + ", " + price.substring(0, price.length()-1));
                final_list.addElement("Title: " + name.substring(7, name.length()-1) + ", " + price.substring(0, price.length()-1));
                strOutput = "Title: " + name.substring(7, name.length()-1) + ", " + price.substring(0, price.length()-1);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider append the `String`s to a `JTextArea`, wrap this in a `JScrollPane` and then pass that to the `JOptionPane` - for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409387/joptionpane-output-text-copy/16409519#16409519)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `java.swing.TextArea` to build message and `JOptionPane` to display it. Here is short demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextArea textView = new TextArea();
        textView.append("dsddd");
        textView.append("jsdjsd");
        textView.append("qwoqwo");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textView);
    }
```